# Should I apply Underlayment over Grace Ice and Water Shield

Tags: roofing

I am about to re-roof using Grace Ice and Water Shield for the first two courses, then a synthetic underlayment above.

I was considering applying the synthetic underlayment over the Ice and Water as well, as I have read that shingles will often adhere so badly to I&W products that you have to take the decking out to re-roof 20-30 years down the line.

Grace I&W says right on the box that shingles won't adhere to it, and makes re-roofing easy.

Is this true?

Can I skip the extra underlayment?

Comment: "*Grace Ice and Water Shield for the first two courses, then a synthetic underlayment above*".  What is your final roofing product? What are the installation requirements for that?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues here: 1) manufacturers installation instructions, 2) substitute a non-manufacturers product

1) I’m always amazed that people don’t think they need to follow the manufactures installation instructions.

General Motors designs, builds, tests and know what their cars can do. They tell us what to use in the gas tank and how to maintain it. Why would you do something else?

Here are the instructions for GAF shingles.  https://www.gaf.com/en-us/document-library/documents/productdocuments/residentialroofingdocuments/roofdeckprotectiondocuments/feltbusterdocuments/FeltBuster_Installation_Instructions.pdf  Please note “Step 2”. They tell you what to use for underlayment, including their proprietary version of “Ice & Water Shield” called WeatherWatch and StormGuard.

Please note that they require an underlayment over their I&W shield.

2) So you have a problem 5 years after you’ve installed your 30 year roof...what to do? You call in the GAF rep because you want to collect on the guarantee.

He’s going to say “the guarantee is voided”...of course. Why wouldn’t he???

Now to answer your question, yes I think you can use I&W Shield and no you don’t need an additional underlayment on top...at your own risk...but why?

(Btw, the reason they probably want an underlayment on top is to protect the rubber membrane. They know idiots will throw bundles down on the deck, walk on it with crap on their boots, etc. and damage the membrane.)